# Set time range for iTunes Recently Added

Tags: itunes

Currently iTunes' Recently Added section only extends back around three months (I think) and I'd like it go back further than that, like 1 or 2 years, say.

Does anyone know how to change this?

Answer (score 2):

Right click the playlist & Edit - it's a Smart Playlist, so you can set any parameters you like, including how far back in time it should look...

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm talking about the Recently Added in My Music, not the Recently Added playlist.